# Can pytest write the junit xml result into a string or an xml object?

Tags: python, xml, unit-testing, junit, pytest

Pytest lets you to output the test result into an xml file on disk by using the `junitxml` option, which is convenient:

```
pytest --junitxml=output.xml
```

My question is, is there any way to let pytest write the same xml formatted output into a string or an xml object such as ElementTree?

Why do I want this? We have a service to run unit tests on a schedule, and we want to extract some results from the xml output and customize it, so that we can send the results via email or save them to a SQL table. It would be nice if we don't have to first save the result to disk, and then read it back to memory, and finally delete it the file on disk.

Comment: Have you tried using `-` as the filenane and see if it writes to stdout?

Comment: Thanks Klaus. I hadn't, but I just tried, and it writes the output to a file named "-".